# Why Http Get action is called instead of Http post action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post, form-submit, submit-button

I'm working with MVC and spent whole day getting stuck with this problem. Here is code at the controller:

```
public class CMController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return View("SignUpPage");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SignUp(User u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (CmdbEntities dc = new CmdbEntities())
            {
                dc.Users.Add(u);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                u = null;
                ViewBag.Message = ("Successfully sign on");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = ("Error");
        }
        return View("Welcome");
    }

}
```

Here is the SignUpPage.cshtml view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "CM", FormMethod.Post))
    {  
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px 50px">
            <label> First name:</label>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Enter first name", ID="FirstName"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px 50px">
            <label >Last name:</label>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Enter first name", ID="LastName"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"  style="padding:5px 50px">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Enter email", ID="Email", type="email"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"  style="padding:5px 50px">
            <label >User name:</label>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Enter user name", ID="UserName"})
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group"  style="padding:5px 50px">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Enter password", ID="Password", type="password"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"  style="padding:5px 50px">
            <label for="pwd">Confirm password:</label>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Re-enter password", ID="_password", type="password"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"  style="padding:5px 50px">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" ID="SignUp" class="btn btn-success" value="Sign Up" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

The problem is, when load page first time, the action SignUp() is called which is correct. But when submit the form, SignUp() is called again instead of the post action SignUp(User u).

One more problem, even the form has post method, when click submit the url contains input information just like get method, I don't understand.

Here is the page html source of form tag.

```
<form action="/CM/SignUp" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="VJ0YcQr1Z-l3Qo717pRpZNT-QtL59G2EJXy2JQL8NFnOm-XoNnAD-8T-Itz3i1EboGj0bhpBf2G26ifxm4F5ZRyKimkOyZW1AxZ3ckPNuRk1" />
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Have you considered adding `[HttpGet]` attribute for the first `SignUp()` action, the theory behind is that ASP.Net's routing will then know which Action method to call based upon which method has been used.

Comment: If you checked the rendered HTML, is it what you expect?

Comment: @chridam if you not specify the method, it is get by default

Comment: @Levesque yeah, the html is find, particularly the form tag has action with post method

Comment: This seemed baffling to me so I threw together a new project and used your controller and view to test it. It worked as expected. Something else is going on in your situation. One thing to try would be to use a tool like Fiddler to make sure your form is actually posting back all the information. If model binding were failing for some reason that might explain why it was selecting the no-arg version of SignUp.

Comment: I found out the problem, I made a mistake that putting extra form tag outside. The result is so unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try adding 
    [AllowAnonymous]

to the post method?

Did you activate global authorization anywhere 
    System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
?